# Is there any way to 'cancel' a using statement in the IDisposable constructor?

Tags: c#

I have a custom class that implements IDisposable, that I use to wrap code in so that I can automatically run a function when the block ends:

```
class SdCardOperation : IDisposable {
    SdCardOperation() { SdCardInUse = true; }
    void Dispose() { SdCardInUse = false; }
}

using(new SdCardOperation()) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

(simplified example)

I would like to, if possible, modify my class so that it can check if, for instance, there isn't an SD card inserted, and if so, silently not run the contents of the using block.  I tried calling a function instead:

```
IDisposable DoSdCardOperation() {
   if(NoSdcard) return null;
   return new SdCardOperation();
}
```

but even when the IDisposable the using block receives is null, it still runs the child block.

By my understanding, if I throw an exception in the constructor, that will 'cancel' the using block, but I'd still have to catch the exception

Comment: This can't be done with `using` but it could be done with lambadas, are you interested in that answer?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am interested in that answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Please share that answer

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that was my original solution actually, but I can't use edit and continue inside a lambda, and it was very annoying, so I switched to using blocks...

Comment: @zacaj Well, other people where interested in seeing that answer so I posted it anyway, you don't have to accept it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know it's not intended for this purpose, but it's the closest language construct I've found, besides what Scottchamberlain suggested, which doesn't work for me for other reasons

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's not the Dispose block that I want to skip.  Returning null from my DoSdCardOperation() does result in the Dispose block not being run, but I want to make the using block's contents not run.

Comment: @zacaj If you use Visual Studio 2015 [you should be able to use Edit and Continue inside lambadas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/04/29/net-announcements-at-build-2015/) (see the section "More EnC – Lambda and Async Task support"). I just tested it myself and was able to do it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's great to know!  Sadly my job uses 2013, so I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with just `using` however if you make a function that accepts a `Action<SdCardOperation>` you can have it conditionally run the code.

```
class SdCardOperation : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs a action on the SdCardOperation only if there is a SD card available.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action to perform</param>
    /// <returns>True if the action was run, false if it was not.</returns>
    public static bool RunOnSdCard(Action<SdCardOperation> action)
    {
        using (var operation = new SdCardOperation())
        {
            if (operation.NoSdcard)
                return false;

            action(operation);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Your other code here.
}
```

You would use it like

```
bool workWasDone = SdCardOperation.RunOnSdCard((operation) =>
{
    //Do work here with operation
});
//You can check workWasDone here to see if anything was done or not.
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a property `bool WillRunMyExitCode` to the class.  Check its value in the `Dispose()` method, and work accordingly.

Comment: wouldn't the Dispose() method not be called till after the code in the using block (which is what I want to skip) has run?

Comment: You can't cancel the call to the Dispose method but you can control what actually HAPPENS within the method.

Comment: I don't want to cancel the call to the dispose method (which is possible, if you return null, then it can't call Dispose, since it has no reference to call), I want to cancel the contents of the using block that run before Dispose() is called

Comment: I think you are missing the whole point of the using block.  The code inside the block will execute.  Why don't you just use an if-then statement *inside* the using block???

Comment: I could, but then I'd be duplicating that if statement all around my codebase (which is what I've done right now, since I don't know of a way to do what I want).  Since I already had some code (the IDisposable class) that was designed specifically for the use case, I hoped there was a way to build the check in, since the check is inherent to the use case

Comment: Then go with Scott Chamberlain's example, with the delegate.